# How long does it take to fine-tune XLNet?

Tags: nlp, bert, finetuning, pretraining

XLNet takes a lot more time than BERT during **pre-training**. This results in XLNet performing better than BERT in over 20 NLP tasks. How long does XLNet take for **fine-tuning** (let's assume this is running on Google Colab)?

(Let's assume a text summarization task with around 4000 examples)

Comment: It depends on the difficulty of the downstream task.

Comment: Let's assume a text summarization task with around 4000 examples